# fusion charts are not displaying in IE and Firefox but displaying in chrome, when exporting div contents to image by using html2canvas

Tags: asp.net

When exporting div contents to an image,fusion charts that are present in the div are not displaying in image when exported to IE and firefox
but displaying in chrome

I am using html2canvas to export div contents to image

please help me how to fix this browser compatability

i used following code:
below button is used in .aspx page to download as image button :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" class="pull-right" style="margin-left:16px;"  runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/jpg-20.png" Height="17px" Width="18px" UseSubmitBehavior="false"   OnClick="btnExport_Click" OnClientClick=" return ConvertToImage(this)" />
```

javascript function :

```
function ConvertToImage() {      
        html2canvas($("#<%=divexportimage.ClientID %>")[0]).then(function (canvas) {         
               var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
               $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
               __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");                  
           });
   return false;
    }
```

.cs code:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/PNG";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
        filename=Mass Save Data.png");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```

by using above code i am able to export div contents to image, but in that image fusion charts are not displaying in IE and chrome whereas it's showing in chromoe.
Please help  me how to fix this issue
Thanks in advance.